# Why can't multiple deities co-exist

Tags: quran, allah

Al-Mu'minun 23:91

> مَا ٱتَّخَذَ ٱللَّهُ مِن وَلَدٍ وَمَا كَانَ مَعَهُۥ
> مِنْ إِلَٰهٍۚ إِذًا لَّذَهَبَ كُلُّ إِلَٰهٍۭ بِمَا خَلَقَ وَلَعَلَا
> بَعْضُهُمْ عَلَىٰ بَعْضٍۚ سُبْحَٰنَ ٱللَّهِ عَمَّا يَصِفُونَ

English - Sahih International

> Allāh has not taken any son, nor has there ever been with Him any deity. [If there had been], then each deity would
> have taken what it created, and some of them would have [sought to]
> overcome others. Exalted is Allāh above what they describe [concerning
> Him].

If mere humans can co-exist and co-operate then why can't infinitely wiser divine beings? Even hostile entities like USA and Russia understand the consequences of going nuclear. So if there are multiple godly beings, wouldn't they understand the consequences of unleashing the destruction they are capable of?

Comment: Whoever downvotes the question, please point out the problem with the question.

Comment: Multiple deities cannot exist as this will contradict each other, this belief is used in the chrisitan belief.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Greenix_3 what is the contradiction?

Comment: What your talking here about is the christian belief @TruthSeeker418, if two gods suppose another thing this will contradict each other and it wont make sense.

Comment: I would like to see an answer based on Islam. As far as I know, it is by definition: there can be but one GOD, but additionally many kinds of *strong ones*, call them angels or daemons or whatever.  In Greek, θεός (theos) refers to the ancient pagan Olympic gods, none of which is almighty, as you can see by the numerous tales about them.